# ExtJS 5 Custom Theme Testing

Tags: testing, themes, extjs5

I recently started to create custom theme for ExtJS 5 by Sencha.

Following http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/core_concepts/theming.html I managed to create ThemeDemoApp, inherit `ext-theme-neptune`, change `$base-color` to green and refresh/rebuild ThemeDemoApp with `my-custom-theme`. All ok.

My problem is, **ThemeDemoApp is quite poor for testing** a custom theme. A panel, tab, button and a modal window. That's it?

After bit of googling I bumped into http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/themes/index.html. (Why isn't this mentioned in the guide?!) Heading says: **View and test every Ext component against bundled Ext Themes, or your own custom themes.**

My question is: **How?** How do I test my own custom theme against this example? Do I have to dig into the source (themes.js) and build such page/application myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples - including the Theme tester - is included in the ExtJS download.

You can modify the list of themes available by editing the `shared/options-toolbar.js` file.

To get it to find your theme, you'll either need to name it similar to the others (`ext-theme-name`), or modify `themes.js` accordingly.

Or you could just hack the `theme.js` file to hardcode your theme.

(Ext JS 4 used to create an example page for themes automatically - it doesn't seem to do that now, though)

Answer (score 0):

According to advice at [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/) I decided to load both `options-toolbar.js` and `themes.js` (with just minor modification - commenting out Ext.onReady(...) function in `themes.js`) and I used functions `getBasicPanel()`, `getCollapsedPanel()`, etc. in my own application to create the same testing page (absolute-layout container that fits the page).

Anyhow, I guess Robert's answer is the correct one - there is no prearranged, ready-to-use functionality from Sencha :-(