# Theme Development: How to display all Ext.JS UI Elements

Tags: user-interface, extjs, extjs5, theming

Is there e.g. a view/main.js file anywhere with all ExtJS UI Elements, so that I see the changes, while I edit scss-files?

I imagine something like that, but with all possible UI-Elements: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/themes/index.html

There is also a all views theming template (https://market.sencha.com/extensions/all-views-theming-template) but I don't know how to use it. (It requires Sencha Architect but I don't use it)

thank you

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280892/extjs-5-custom-theme-testing

Comment: thank you but, this is not a duplicate (it is extjs4 and my question is about extjs5, these are different concepts). Notwithstanding the above, that the question has also not been answered over there.. 

There is still no prearranged, ready-to-use functionality from Sencha :(

Comment: Can somebody remove the subject above "This question may already have an answer here" ?

Comment: Ext JS 4 and 5 are fairly similar. There's no baked-in way to do what you want and the other question provides a workaround (using the Theme example app) that should be good for both versions.

Comment: I currently go an another way with Sencha Architect, may be I've a better solution soon.